# Connecting usb to uart device to android device >3.1

Tags: java, android, linux, usb, drivers

I know that the latest android device with API>3.1 support USB host mode or USB OTG that allows you to connect a lot of usb devices like flash disks,mouse,keyboard etc. but can you connect any device that does not have common general drivers like [USB to uart device](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6_64&products_id=64),printers,cameras

I have linux drivers for these devices in source codes as .c files, So is there a way that I can build and install those drivers to an android phone and make the usb devices usable on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind ! I found a standard way for my device [here](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=230&pcid=41) It provides interface through native code and IPC and official library from manufacturer

Answer (score 2):

To use linux drivers for android you have to compile your own kernel or kernel module. If you expect your app to be used by other people, this is not a feasible way.

For some low bandwidth USB devices it is possible to write user space drivers in java using the [Host API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html). For USB-UARTs there is the [usb-serial-for-android](https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/) project that is implementing a user space driver based on this API.

Comment: Oh so you mean I should implement the driver (such as its protocol) that I have using usb Host api. Hmm seems a bit promising ! I will give it a shot. After all I have the source for the driver.


So can anyone Help me understand the protocol the driver is going to use to communicate?

Comment: @Allahjane You don't have to implement it yourself. As my answer says there is already a project implementing such drivers.